# How to calculate large numbers in C++?

Tags: c++, largenumber

I am quite new to programming, and I came across this 'simple' question to calculate the the sum of an arithmetic progression:

I know the formula is like : `(2*a + (n-1)*d) * n/2`

`a`, `d`, `n` are `int`. `n` can be around 10000, and `a` and `d` can be up to 100000.

I know that by simply writing:

```
int result = (2*a + (n-1)*d) * n/2;
```

will not work

*Edit:
So it works when I write something like:

```
long long result = (2*a+(long long)(n-1)*d)*n/2;
```

But just to clarify whether the following reasoning is correct:

Because of the `(long long)` wrapper, `(n-1)*d` is changed to the type `long long`.

Then `(2*a+(long long)(n-1)*d)` becomes `long long` also after the addition? And so are the following operations?

Thanks so much for reading.

Comment: You can use a "bignum" library, such as [The GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library](http://gmplib.org/).

Comment: it should work, but to be sure please add your code, so we get to know why !

Comment: But what you should do first is to show us the exact input which give wrong output, and the actual (wrong) and expected output. Please edit your question to include that information.

Comment: `after I add some 'long' or 'long long'`. **How** did you add that?

Comment: To clarify @Engine's comment, this not produce overflows in `long` precision if `a` is much smaller than `n*d`. OP, please show inputs and expected outputs, I guess you might have an issue with loss of precision.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. It works now, but I still not quite confident with what I am writing, please help me check whether my reasoning is correct?

Comment: You may use `long long` for `a`, `d`, `n` variables.

Comment: @zycuber: Yes, your reasoning captures what happens ... `n-1` is forced to be treated as a `long long` and then all other variables are automatically converted to the same type as well since in arithmetic operations all operands need to have the same type. Still it would help if you would provide a complete example of *all* input variables, an expected output and what you actually see.

Comment: @BenjaminBannier Thank you for your reply! Actually this is online graded so I am not sure about the test cases. I tried with a = 99999, d = 99999, and n = 9999 just now, and it returns the correct output which is 4999450005000, then I could as well pass all the other test cases.

Answer (score 0):

Integer types in C++ have a fixed number of bits. The exact number varies from computer to computer, but `int` is always *at least* 16 bits, `long` is at least 32 bits and `long long` is at least 64 bits. If you mix these, the result type is the longest type. However, you'll lose one bit to the sign unless you use the corresponding `unsigned` types.

So, in your example you have numbers in the range 10^4 * 10^5 * 10^5, so 10^14. That's well in range of `long long` (~10^19), but not in the minimum range of `int`. Now `int` often is bigger than the minimum 16 bits, but still it's usually only 32 bits. That explains why it didn't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

In this expression:

```
long long result = (2*a+(long long)(n-1)*d)*n/2;
```

the cast of `(long long)(n-1)` converts the value of `n-1` to a `long long` (so 64-bits minimum). This means that any math done in conjuction with this will also need to be converted to `long long`, so `d` is `long long`, and `n/2` will be long long. `2*a` also needs to be converted to `long long`. In other words, everything in your expression is calculated as 64-bit numbers (or potentially larger in some machines - not that I've ever seen one with larger `long long`).

A 64-bit integer will easily hold numbers far greater than `10000*100000` (you'd need another 4-5 digits on each side to overflow a 64-bit number), but numbers in that range could cause an overflow in 32-bit math, since it's larger than ~2000000000.